# How to fix not visible element (burgermenu) after trigger toggleClass statement

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, safari

I am currently struggling with issue happening only on iPhone with safari browsers [on this page](https://immo-hofmann.de).

After clicking on the burger menu icon, the element which had to expand don't show up on the highest layer (see image attached).

This only happens in mobile safari.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgNrR.png)
Hope someone could help me out.

```js
 $('#toggler-btn').on('click',function(){
    $('#main-menu').toggleClass('mobile_menu');
  });
```

```html
<nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg mobile_menu">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CSS` Set

```
.navbar{
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that don't helped, the element still shows up in the background.